# Color changing when excel sheets (exported from SSRS) are merged

Tags: c#, .net, colors, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

I encountered a strange problem where in I have developed 3 reports in SSRS 2008 solution and exported them to excel sheets which exported with the colors (green, red, orange) that are intended. When I try to merge them into one excel sheet by copying all the sheets, I found that the colors are changing wierdly and I had to change them manually. I tried mimicing the same merging using C# code which was also not fruiful.

Changing the colors manually is really tiresome because I have 64 reports in total. Please suggest me something to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: These 3 reports exist in 3 separate excel files correct?

Comment: Yes. All the 3 reports exist in 3 seperate excel files and I need to merge them and make a single consolidated excel file.

Comment: Give me a few, I'm working on an app for us, I have use for this as well and have never really got around to making my code that does what you want into a separate app/codebase. I'll keep you updated on here.

Comment: Think it's done. Give me a sec to publish it out there for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 4:

I made this console app to mimic what you are doing.

```
namespace ExcelConsole
{
using System.IO;

using ExcelCombine;

class Program
{
    public static string Thepath { get; set; }
    public static string TheFirstFile { get; set; }
    public string[] files = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thepath = @"C:\Users\J\Desktop\TestingFolder\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Thepath);
        TheFirstFile = files[0];
        ExcelEngine.CombineWorkBooks(Thepath, "*.xls", Thepath, false, TheFirstFile);
    }
}
}
```

I used the class that you should already have. In the folder "TestingFolder" that you see referenced above, I placed the template and the copies with the formulas. After running the app it combined them just fine and maintained the formatting/formulas.

Edit 5:

I think I may have ended up with something after all.

In that excel code that I gave you, change this:

```
 sheetToCopy.Copy(defaultWorksheet)
```

To this:

```
sheetToCopy.Range["A1", "AC60"].Copy();
newBook.Activate();
newBook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing,defaultWorksheet);
newBook.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", "Z50"].Select();

newBook.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme);
```

What this did for me was keep the coloring and copy the data, but no matter which paste option I used, the column widths did not copy.

Hope this helps even a little bit.

Comment: Add xlApp.CutCopyMode = XlCutCopyMode.xlCopy; after the creation line: xlApp = new Application(); . I went through a few forums and that may help us out.